# Unable to Delete User Object in AD windows server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, ldap, replication

OS - Window Server 2008 ( Domain Controller )
One User Object in AD is Creating Problem as well as i am unable to delete it manually also. Please see the below Error.
[image]

In Event viewer i am getting below Error
[image]

So i thought to Delete it from ldap.exe, still i am getting the below error
[image]

I also tried to Repair Database, via Safe mode - Active Directory Repair mode. i.e by esentutl /g c:\Windows\ntds\ntds.dit
and also with esentutl /p c:\windows\ntds\ntds.dit
but it also given me error.

Your help will be really very helpful and Thanks for your Time & Effort.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to resolve this problem by referring to the Microsoft knowledge base article for the related error here:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/837932

Answer (score 1):

Did you notice the NTDS ISAM error?  Your darabase is corrupt.  Demote the dc, run chkdsk, then promote it again.